# How to fix predictive typing in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I am using Gmail and Chrome. When I type `(FYI)` it always defaults to `FOR YOUR INFORMATION`. Does anyone know how to turn this off?

Answer (score 1):

- go to **Settings**
- under **General** there is **Smart Compose**

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks but this did not help. I will note that when performing a web search the same thing happens so I believe this setting is outside of gmail. In fact, as I was typing my questions the (FYI) defaulted to FOR YOUR INFORMATION thus why I added the parenthesis.

Comment: @Rob well, then this question is kinda redundant. check if you don't have any autocorrection extensions